# ps -xa | grep node to kill specific process

Tags: command-line, process

I am currently using the following command to get a process:

```
ps -xa | grep node
```

Which results in the following:

```
13611 ?        Sl     0:03 /opt/brackets/Brackets-node /opt/brackets/node-core
20713 pts/1    Sl     0:00 node --harmony app.js
20838 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep node
```

I use the command `kill -9 20713` to kill the `node --harmony app.js` process.

How can I kill the `node --harmony app.js` every single time with one command? I am tired of typing in the process number every time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `pkill`:

```
pkill node
```

This would match the other command as well, so fine tune it:

```
pkill -f "node --harmony app.js"
```

This matches the full command line (`-f`) exactly, so it should only hit the desired command.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `killall`. The simplest syntax is:

```
killall "Process_name"
```

In you case:

```
killall "node --harmony app.js"
```

The upside of `killall` is that it will match the exact name so there is no chance of killing other processes unwantedly.

Although you can use `-r` option to express the process as a regular expression pattern like `pkill`.

Check [`man killall`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/killall.1) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Use an alias and your own "command word" for it.

E.G.go to your home Dir and create the file .bash_aliases

Put the following text into the file

```
alias nerdalert='pkill -f "node --harmony app.js"'
```

and then search in your home folder for your .bashrc looking for this part and make sure it's not commented out.

```
# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

Now type into your terminal

```
source /home/${USER}/.bash_aliases
```

and try your brand new "command" a.k.a. alias

`nerdalert`

Enjoy ^^

Comment: I am going to do that haha.